# How did the spelling of 'mien' evolve?

Tags: etymology, orthography

I ask only about **mien**'s definition of ['A person’s look or manner'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mien#mien), and not the [Yao people](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/yao#Yao-2).

> [OED:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/118275?rskey=DgonaP&result=1&isAdvanced=false) **Etymology:**  Probably a merging of two words of distinct origins:
>    (i) shortened < [demean n.](http://libsta28.lib.cam.ac.uk:2163/view/Entry/49608#eid7077534);
>   (ii) a loan < Middle French, French ***mine*** countenance, facial expression (13th cent. in Old French in phrase *faire mines* to grimace, make faces), appearance, manner, air (late 15th cent.), probably < Breton *min* muzzle (see below).

I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but is the English spelling of **mien** strange or startling? If it's shortened or derived from 'demean' (as OED says above), would 'mean' be more natural?
  For example, modern French still retains the spelling « [mine](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/mine) » to mean 'appearance, look'.

Comment: Never heard of it before. I would associate *mien* with *demeano(u)r*, perhaps the two are related.

Comment: It is paradoxical that this sense in French is spelled *mine*, which in English is the pronoun, which in French would be *le mien*, or *la mienne*.

Comment: @WS2 +1. I missed that insightful observation. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised it people simply confused the French `mine` and `mien` when the word was borrowed, and adopted the wrong spelling (perhaps even _because_ it looked more foreign). Strange things happen when words jump across languages.

Comment: Also, strange spellings sometimes happen due to fashion. Like _shoppe_, which became popular because it looks archaic or French, and lent an air of charm or quaintness to the establishment.

Comment: There is also the German word die Miene meaning facial expression. There might be a connection. I didn't study the German word as English mien is rare and literary.

Comment: DWDS says German Miene is a loan from French la mine from Breton min beak,  mouth, snout.  http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Miene

Answer (score 1):

Every word in English is spelled the way it is because somebody spelled it that way at some point, and other people followed suit. There is no governing body that decides these things like in the French language. Words are made up all the time, taken from other languages all the time, and because English is spoken so broadly, imported from other regional English dialects all the time.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about a specific word. If you don't know the answer, why not just leave a comment?